# Matplotplt Label is not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The label name is not showing up in graph in jupyter notebook. It's not even throwing error. Below is my code, the label I am talking about is basically legend marks which display top most right side of the graph.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

gasdf = pd.read_csv('gas_prices.csv')

plt.plot(gasdf['Year'],gasdf['USA'],label='USA')
plt.plot(gasdf['Year'],gasdf['UK'],label='UK')
plt.plot(gasdf.Year,gasdf['Australia'],label='AUS')
plt.show()
```

Below is the sample data.

```
Year

Australia

Canada

France

Germany

Italy

Japan

Mexico

South Korea

UK

USA



0
1990 NaN 1.87 3.63 2.65 4.59 3.16 1.00 2.05 2.82 1.16 

1
1991 1.96 1.92 3.45 2.90 4.50 3.46 1.30 2.49 3.01 1.14 

2
1992 1.89 1.73 3.56 3.27 4.53 3.58 1.50 2.65 3.06 1.13
```

Below is the graph which describe above data.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Legend is showing after adding `plt.legend()` before `plt.show()`.